# Declaração de libs do bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-3

Tenho declarado no código as libs do bootstrap assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O meu erro está na página, que quando clicar no ícone do menu, o mesmo não expandi
Veja:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguma sugestão?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Pousada Deutsches Haus</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/estilo.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"   href="resources/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
<script type="text/javascript" scr="resources/js/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" scr="resources/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-xs-8">
        <img src="resources/imagens/logo_deut.png"> 
    </div>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top col-xs-4">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="navbar-inverse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="navbar-header navbar-right">
                    <p class="navbar-text">
                    <a href="#" class="navbar-link">Username</a>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: Troque navbar-collapse por navbar-inverse no data-target

Comment: Não resolveu tbm, alguma outra sugestão?

Comment: No lugar de colocar uma imagem com o HTML poderia editar e colocar seu HTML em texto aqui para que a gente possa editar e descobrir rapidamente o problema?

Comment: Nada ainda, parece ser entre a declaração do js do bootstrap e do jquery

Comment: Segue código código em texto lá na pergunta

Comment: troque "scr" por `src`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Na chamada do Javascript vc colocou `scr=` e o correto é `src=`.

Ficaria assim:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Comment: Bingoo! Valeu fera.

Aproveitando, não consigo implementar este exemplo de menu collapse em desktop http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/151555/45854

Veja se consegue se no seu ambiente funciona

Comment: como dica coloca seu estilo <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/estilo.css">  abaixo do estilo bootstrap, caso for sobrepor algum estilo

Comment: Obrigado fera, resolveu meu problemas aqui, abraço!

Comment: Alisson, se a resposta acima resolveu seu problema não se esqueça de aceitá-la para recompensar o autor.