# Menu collapse em desktop

Tags: html, bootstrap-3, menu

Segui como neste exemplo http://www.bootply.com/122826

Mas na página meu resultado foi:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Nesse mesmo exemplo (http://www.bootply.com/122826) ja tem a resposta

```
$(window).resize(function() {
var viewportWidth = $(window).width();
$('#monitor').html(viewportWidth);
```

});